# Change background of specific selectable() jquery

Tags: jquery, html, colors, background, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm trying to change the color of one specific element in a selectable function using jquery.

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content" id="s1">Option 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" id="s2">Option 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" id="s3">Option 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" id="s4">Option 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" id="s5">Option 5</li>
</ol>
```

I just want to change the background color where id="s4", but I dont't know if that's possible.

The function is:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable();      
});
```

I already tried with jquery and css but still nothing.

Comment: is this for any kind of dropdown?

Comment: No. I'm trying to do something like this: http://jqueryui.com/selectable/, but with one of them with a different color.

Comment: Ok...thanks for the link....I have created the same demo...pls check my fiddle from answer

Comment: I already checked. The second helped me very much! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [create](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-create) event

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        create: function(event, ui) {
            $("#s4").css('background', 'red');
        },
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.selected).css('background', 'yellow');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jet1h78e/)

Comment: Thanks! But I'd like to change the color only when selected

Comment: @MiniKing17-Tiago, then you can use [selected](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected) see https://jsfiddle.net/jet1h78e/ or https://jsfiddle.net/844jc0ce/

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a css hack for that

```
#selectable #s4.ui-selected { background: red; }
```

Comment: @MiniKing17 - Tiago, please check this hack once. :)

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rushil151/cckvoa7m/)

Script :

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myGrid").click(function(){
            $(".myGrid").each(function() {
                $(this).css('background-color', '');
            });
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
           }); 
        });
```

Html :

```
<ol id="selectable">
        <li class="ui-widget-content myGrid" id="s1">Option 1</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content myGrid" id="s2">Option 2</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content myGrid" id="s3">Option 3</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content myGrid" id="s4">Option 4</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content myGrid" id="s5">Option 5</li>
</ol>
```